# Still bug in NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, bugs

Executing in 13.2 on Windows 10

```
NMaximize[{Abs[ Sum[Cot[theta] Evaluate[
D[SphericalHarmonicY[k, n, theta, phi], theta]] /. {theta -> 1,
phi -> 1}, {n, -k, k}]], k ∈ PositiveIntegers}, k]
```

, I obtain

> `{4.82235, {k -> 9}}`

The above result contradicts the result of

```
DiscretePlot[ Abs[Sum[Cot[theta] Evaluate[
D[SphericalHarmonicY[k, n, theta, phi], theta]] /. {theta -> 1, 
phi -> 1}, {n, -k, k}]], {k, 6, 15}]
```

[image]

That is [CASE:4909302]. Since the `NMaximize` command is [updated in 13.2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn132.html), I hoped the bug has been fixed. Is there a workaround?  The command

```
NMaximize[{Abs[Sum[Cot[theta] Evaluate[
D[SphericalHarmonicY[k, n, theta, phi], theta]] /. {theta -> 1,
phi -> 1}, {n, -k, k}]], k ∈ PositiveIntegers}, k, 
Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 1}]
```

is running without any response on my comp for a long time.

Comment: Maybe I am confusing myself a bit, but from the way you wrote it seems that this is an old bug still present in `13.2.0`. Do I have a correct understanding?

Comment: @bmf: Thank you for your interest to the question. Yes, you do correctly understand it. My question is about a workaround.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Today got a bit crazy a bit too quickly, so not sure if I have the time to test now. I do get the same behavior that you describe. Just a suggestion: if this has been reported in the past under the `bugs` tag, perhaps you could update the older thread such that we know how it evolves from one version to the next :-)

Comment: @bmf: There is no "older thread ". I didn't submit [CASE:4909302] as a question.

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood. Perhaps a noteworthy comment: `NMaximize` without any `Method` specification gives the same output as `"DifferentialEvolution"`.  Then, `"NelderMead"` gives a different output and the same is true for `"SimulatedAnnealing"`. Finally, `"RandomSearch"` failed to converge but gave a result, which as you guessed is different from the previous ones. However, if we use as a method `"NonlinearInteriorPoint"` it gives the same answer as `"RandomSearch"` without any warnings. I tried `"MeshSearch"` but after 2 minutes it was still going and I have to run.

Comment: Not the cleverest thing I ever tried, but I was curious to see how it behave with different methods.

Comment: @bmf: Many thanks from me to you for your valuable comment.